# What does this warning from lavaan for cfa() mean?

Tags: compiler-warnings, r-lavaan

I am running a CFA using lavaan and have the following error. It is odd because I ran the code before and it was not giving me this error...

```
lavaan WARNING:
    the optimizer (NLMINB) claimed the model converged, but not all
    elements of the gradient are (near) zero; the optimizer may not
    have found a local solution use check.gradient = FALSE to skip
    this check
```

Here is the code for the model (N = 327):

```
comp_model <- '
LC =~ LC_1 + LC_2 + LC_3 + LC_4 + LC_5 + LC_6 + LC_7 + LC_8 + LC_9 + LC_10 + LC_11 + LC_12 + LC_13 + LC_14 + LC_15 + LC_16 + LC_17 + LC_18 + LC_19 + LC_20 + LC_21 + LC_22 + LC_23 + LC_24 + LC_25 + LC_26 + LC_27 + LC_28 + LC_29 + LC_30 + LC_31 + LC_32 + LC_33 + LC_34 + LC_35 + LC_36 + LC_37 + LC_38 + LC_39 + LC_40 + LC_41 + LC_42 + LC_43 + LC_44 + LC_45 + LC_46 + LC_47 + LC_48 + LC_49 + LC_50 + LC_51 + LC_52 + LC_53 + LC_54 + LC_55 + LC_56 + LC_57 + LC_58 + LC_59 + LC_60 + LC_61
MTL =~ MTL_1 + MTL_2 + MTL_3 + MTL_4 + MTL_5 + MTL_6 + MTL_7 + MTL_8 + MTL_9 + MTL_10
WB =~ WB_E_1 + WB_E_2 + WB_E_3 + WB_S_1 + WB_S_2 + WB_S_3 + WB_S_4 + WB_S_5 + WB_P_1 + WB_P_2 + WB_P_3 + WB_P_4 + WB_P_5 + WB_P_6
Coping =~ Coping_A_1 + Coping_A_2 + Coping_A_3 + Coping_A_4 + Coping_A_5 + Coping_A_6 + Coping_A_7 + Coping_A_8 + Coping_A_9 + Coping_A_10 + Coping_A_11 + Coping_A_12 + Coping_A_13 + Coping_A_14 + Coping_PR_1 + Coping_PR_2 + Coping_PR_3 + Coping_PR_4 + Coping_PR_5 + Coping_PR_6 + Coping_PR_7 + Coping_PR_8 + Coping_PR_9 + Coping_PR_10 + Coping_PR_11 + Coping_PR_12 + Coping_APS_1 + Coping_APS_2 + Coping_APS_3 + Coping_APS_4 + Coping_APS_5 + Coping_APS_6 + Coping_APS_7 + Coping_APS_8 + Coping_APS_9 + Coping_APS_10
ENG =~ ENG_1 + ENG_2 + ENG_3 + ENG_4 + ENG_5 + ENG_6 + ENG_7 + ENG_8 + ENG_9
PsyCap =~ ENG_10 + ENG_11 + ENG_12 + ENG_13 + ENG_14 + ENG_15 + ENG_16 + ENG_17 + ENG_18 + ENG_19
E =~ Trait_1_E + Trait_6_E_rev
A =~ Trait_2_A_rev + Trait_7_A
C =~ Trait_3_C + Trait_8_C_rev
ES =~ Trait_4_ES_rev + Trait_9_ES
O =~ Trait_5_O + Trait_10_O_rev
'
```

Here is the code for the fit:

```
lavaan::cfa(model = comp_model, 
                data = CFA_data,   
                std.lv = F)
```

The fit takes a long time to run, then gives me the warning and the summary code

```
summary(comp_model_fit,
    standardized=TRUE, # or FALSE??
    rsquare = TRUE,
    ci = TRUE,
    fit.measures=TRUE)
```

Gives me this output (first line:

```
lavaan 0.6-12 did NOT end normally after 296 iterations
** WARNING ** Estimates below are most likely unreliable

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                       355

  Number of observations                           327


Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|) ci.lower ci.upper   Std.lv  Std.all
  LC =~                                                                                   
    LC_1              1.000                               1.000    1.000    0.215    0.342
    LC_2              1.234       NA                         NA       NA    0.265    0.460
    LC_3              1.304       NA                         NA       NA    0.280    0.484
    LC_4              1.417       NA                         NA       NA    0.304    0.427
    LC_5              1.294       NA                         NA       NA    0.278    0.427
    LC_6              1.250       NA                         NA       NA    0.268    0.465
```

I'm not sure why the warning is occurring now and not before and how to resolve the issue. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a large model to estimate with only *N* = 327.  One potential source of trouble is that you have (Big-)5 factors with only 2 indicators.  Those often suffer from empirical underidentification issues (e.g., they are only identified in models with substantial enough factor correlations and large enough *N* to estimate them stably; [Steiger, 2002](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/1082-989X.7.2.210)).  You could see whether the same issue occurs when you just fit the model to those 5 factors.  The other factors all have several indicators, so you could try fitting smaller 1-factor models as well, just to see whether the issue occurs with any of them.  It is generally good advice to start small and build up, as it can help narrow down other types of problem, too.